# LINQ to XML At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: xml, linq

I want to get the highest attribute "ID" from my XML file.

My code:

```
    var doc = XElement.Load("invoices.xml");

    var q = (from f in doc.Element("ListOfInvoices").Elements("Invoice")
             orderby f.Attributes("ID") descending
             select f.Attribute("ID")).FirstOrDefault();
```

When in my XML file is one of Invoice code works, but when is for example 2 invoice I have an error:

At least one object must implement IComparable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try casting `f.Attributes("ID")` into an `int` if it's numeric or a `string` if it's alphanumeric like this:

```
var q = (from f in doc.Element("ListOfInvoices").Elements("Invoice")
             orderby (int)f.Attribute("ID") descending
             select f.Attribute("ID")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You cannot cast a list of XmlAttributes to int.. You cannot cast an XmlElement to int. And you cannot cast a string to int.

Comment: @Schiavini: it is an XAttribute NOT an XmlAttribute and yes you can! MSDN say so, the compiler accepts it, why can't you?

Comment: you're right, you can cast XAttribute.. however his problem was the typo at f.Attributes(), which returns XAttribute[].

Comment: @Schiavini: ... and how does that make right your, you can not CAST ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly access `XAttribute.Value` explicitly:

```
doc.Element("ListOfInvoices")
.Elements("Invoice")
.Select(f => f.Attribute("ID").Value)
.OrderByDecending(a => a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo on the orderby. You wrote Attributes instead of Attribute.

You need to use the Value property to get the attribute value:

```
        var q = (
            from f in doc.Element("ListOfInvoices").Elements("Invoice")
            orderby f.Attribute("ID").Value descending
            select f.Attribute("ID").Value
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```